# How the time complexity is calculated for a loop - Swift

Tags: swift, for-loop, data-structures, time-complexity

I have given two sample for loops with different time complexities. One is Quadratic and the other is Logarithmic. Can anyone help me why the time complexities varies, as both code iterate same number of times but with different operations?

What is the factor of time complexity? No of times or operation?

```
//Quadratic O(n^2)
var c = 0
for i in 1...100{
    c = Int(pow(Double(i), 2))
}

//Logarithamic O(log n)
var d = 0
for i in 1...100{
    d = Int(log(Double(i)))
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this may help you https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-of-algorithms-set-4-analysis-of-loops/

Comment: @kenny Thanks for your help, but may I know the exact factor for varying the time complexity of the above example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two loops have the same time complexity - O(1) constant time, because they will always run 100 times. Nothing about them

As you may know time complexity measures how the time needed for an algorithm to run changes as a variable *changes*. For example, this loop has time complexity O(n):

```
for i in 0..<n {
    print(i)
}
```

As `n` increases, the time needed to run that loop increases *linearly*, hence O(n).

This loop would be O(n^2):

```
for i in 0..<(n*n) {
    print(i)
}
```

This loop would be O(log(n)):

```
for i in 0..<Int(log(n)) {
    print(i)
}
```

(Obviously there are other ways of making O(n^2) and O(log(n)) loops)

I think the loops you are given are just supposed to *illustrate* different time complexities by plotting a "graph" of the time needed increases as n increases. As you can see from the screenshot, the O(log(n)) loop plots a log(n) graph.

Comment: anyway this seems helpful, regarding the screenshot, that is actually i taken from the xcode debugging option , Xcode says that my second loop example has log (n) complexity and the first one has quadratic complexity. Not only xcode i have watched some famous youtube channel. It also says the same [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvIx6BecJDI).

Comment: @FaizalMalik You are just using Swift Playground's Playground Quick Look feature to see how a variable has changed over each iteration of the loop. Your loop makes use of this feature to plot a "graph" of the corresponding time complexity.

Comment: yes , It says below code time complexity is O(log n) and you just said its O(1). Which one is correct ? why it differs if both loops are executing the same number of times ?

for i in 1...100{
    d = Int(log(Double(i)))
}

Comment: @FaizalMalik The loops themselves are all O(1), but the _graphs_ they create illustrate different time complexities. So when the guy in the Youtube video say "this loop is quadratic time", he meant "this loop creates a graph that illustrates how the time needed to run a O(n^2) algorithm increases as n increases". An actual O(n^2) loop is shown in my answer.

Comment: “Nothing about them...” - The suspense is killing me! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the time complexity is, effectively, the number of times some constant length task is performed as the number of iterations increases. Needless to say, one shouldn’t confuse the O(n^2) or O(log n) complexity of the loop with calculations of `pow(..., 2)` or `log()` within the loop. Those are two completely different issues.

So this would be a O(n) routine, where the amount of time required increases linearly with the number of iterations, `n`:

```
for i in 0 ..< n {
    // some task whose duration doesn’t not change with respect to `n`
}
```

This would be a classic O(n^2) routine, where the amount of time required increases with the square of the number of iterations, `n`:

```
for i in 0 ..< n {
    for j in 0 ..< n {
        // some task whose duration doesn’t not change with respect to `n`
    }
}
```

A classic example of O(log n) routine would be a [binomial search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) within some already-sorted array, where the amount of time required increases with the log of the number of iterations, `n`. I.e. with only one more iteration, you can find a value within an array of twice the size.

Comment: Thanks Rob, Could you please tell me what is the time complexity of this code below: ?

var d = 0
for i in 1...100{
    d = Int(log(Double(i)))
}

Comment: If you mean `for i in 1...n { d = Int(log(Double(i))) }`, that’s O(n). Again, the fact you call `log` is irrelevant. But, if you really meant `for i in 1...100 {…}`, not referencing `n` at all, then that’s O(1), i.e. make `n` as big as you want, and the speed won’t change. When we talk about time complexity, the question is how time increases as you increase the number of iterations, so by definition, a fixed number of iterations will take a fixed amount of time.